# Как я могу изменить состояние не родительского компонента?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Есть структура компонентов, например:

```
<div>
     <ErrorComponent/>
     <PageComponent props={props}/>
</div>
```

В Page компоненте длинная цепочка компонентов. Цель: из любого компонента, который ниже в цепочке, чем пример выше, мне нужно вызвать метод в классе ErrorComponent, который добавит в массив errors в состоянии этого компонента элемент. Этот метод может быть вызван в любой момент времени после рендера и в любом месте. Состояние ErrorComponent должно обновиться.
Проблема, с которой я столкнулся: я создаю экземпляр этого класса и пытаюсь вызвать метод добавления нового элемента:

```
 const errorDescriptor = new ErrorDescriptor('', null)
    errorDescriptor.handleAddError(new Error('err'))
```

Но react выбрасывает предупреждение, что я не могу изменять состояние компонента, который не смонтирован.

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
>   This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
>   Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
>   class property with the desired state in the ErrorDescriptor
>   component.

Что я делаю не так и есть ли другие способы решения?

Comment: ну так сделайте это  после того как компонент смонтирован внутри жизненного цикла `componentDidMount`.Что тут сложного?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов не совсем понял. Что мне нужно сделать в componentDidMount?

Comment: выполняйте вызов `setState` внутри `componentDidMount`.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов У меня есть отдельный метод в классе для выполнения setState. Я хочу вызывать этот метод из любого места в коде для добавления элемента в state. Как я должен делать это через componentDidMount?

Comment: Вы можете предоставить `codesandbox`?

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-curran-m0kg6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужен в родительском компоненте стейт с ошибками, отдельный компонент, где будут ошибки обрабатываться и компонент, который будет всем компонентам ниже передавать колбэк функцию, которая будет добавлять ошибку в родительский компонент. Вот пример, есть Element1, где ошибку можно добавить при клике, и Element2 где ошибка добавляется при рендере:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  function handleAddError(error) {
    setErrors(errors => [...errors, error]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ErrorElement errors={errors}/>
      <PageElement callback={() => handleAddError}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const ErrorElement = ({errors}) => {
  return <div>{errors.length}</div>;
}

const PageElement = ({callback}) => {
 return <>
    <div>page element</div>
    <Element1 callback={callback}/>
    <Element2 callback={callback}/>
  </>
}

const Element1 = ({callback}) => {
  return <button onClick={callback("some err")}>add</button>
}

const Element2 = ({callback}) => {
  useEffect(callback("error"), []);
  return <div>а тут ошибка при рендере</div>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Можно использовать в таком случае redux, что бы не передавать каждому дочернему компоненту функцию, а делать деспатч только там где необходимо